# Jquery content slider with prev, next

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find a good slider but i did not find anything.

I want a content slider working in `<div>` and I can add next and prev buttons in any place in the html.

Answer (score 1):

Try the jQuery [loopedslider](http://nathansearles.com/loopedslider/), have used it before in other projects, and did the job

Comment: See exhibit A - http://nathansearles.com/loopedslider/example-3.html - top one autoscrolls. Check out the documentation on github - http://github.com/nathansearles/loopedSlider